# Lilypond v2.19 - How do I add a title to the second page of the same score?

Tags: lilypond

I want to add a title to the second page of the same score. How would that be possible?

Here is a template: http://www.lilybin.com/3hii6e/1

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following below the header section will print the title on every page (see [here](http://www.lilybin.com/3hii6e/3)):

```
\paper {
    oddHeaderMarkup = \markup {
        \fill-line
        {
          \fromproperty #'page:page-number-string                   %% left
          \on-the-fly #not-first-page \fromproperty #'header:title  %% center
          " "                                                       %% right
         }
    }
    evenHeaderMarkup = \oddHeaderMarkup
}
```

Essentially, you only need the line that contains the "header:title" (the "center" line). However, in order to have the title in the middle, you also need the "left & right" lines.